# (C++) Deque: Diferenças entre os tipos de acessos às posições

Tags: c++, lista

Estou implementando o Problema da Mochila com Programação Dinâmica em `C++` e escolhi o deque para montar minha lista. Estudando sobre ele, percebi essas duas diferentes formas de acessar uma posição específica da lista:

```
//Retorna o item i da lista mydeque
mydeque[i]
mydeque.at(i)
```

Qual a real diferença entre as duas, já que à primeira vista ambas são idênticas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::deque` e `std::vector` têm duas formas de se acessar elementos de forma indexada:

- Pelo operator colchetes []
- Pela função membro `at`

A diferença básica entre os dois é que a função `at` checa o índice, lançando uma exceção (`std::out_of_range`) em caso de acesso além do tamanho do contêiner.
O operador colchetes assume que sempre vai ser invocado com um índice válido.

Comment: Então a função membro at previne que o programa acesse áreas proibidas da memória?

Comment: Sim, em troca de uma pequena penalidade de desempenho, pois a cada acesso é feito um teste. E você também tem que tratar a exceção, senão seu programa será encerrado de qualquer forma. Usando o operador colchetes você é responsável por garantir que não haverá acessos inválidos.

Answer (score 0):

mideque[i]: acessa o elemento sem verificar a validade do índice
mideque.at(i): acessa o elemento verificando a validade do índice

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_at
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/at